# Using R for simple image/pattern-recognition task?

Tags: r, image-processing, plot, ocr

I have an image with many dots, and I would like to extract from it what is the x-y location of each dot.

I already know how to do this manually (there is a package for doing it).

However, is there some way of doing it automatically ?

(My next question will be - is there a a way, when having an image of many lines, to detect where the lines intersect/"touch each other")

Due to requests in the comments, here is an example for an image to "solve" (i.e: extract the data point locations for it)

```
#riddle 1 (find dots):
plot(cars, pch = 19)
#riddle 2 (find empty center circles):
plot(cars, pch = 1)
#riddle 2 (fine intersection points):
plot(cars, pch = 3)
#riddle 3 (find intersections between lines):
plot(cars, pch = 1, col = "white")
lines(stats::lowess(cars))
abline(v = c(5,10,15,20,25))
```

Thanks, Tal

(p.s: since I am unfamiliar with this field, I am sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or asking something too simple or complex.  Is this [OMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition)?)

Comment: Why are you so secretive about the picture? Can you create fair replica, so we can get our hands dirty? =) Otherwise, all that I can do (and I can't do much, 'cause Dirk already said it) is to point you to particular package. You're still prone on using R as a "general purpose" programming language. I think C is far more appropriate for problems like these...

Comment: Wait a sec... You want to import data from a "paper & pen" questionnaire? O_o
Intersection of lines refers to X-marks?

Comment: Hello aL3xa, the problem I present has came to me in various places.  Each time I solved it "by hand", by I wanted to see if a more general solution could be found (using R).  And BTW, it is funny you are teasing me regarding the "R bein a general purpose language", when a while ago I asked on SO explicitly if that is the case - and people here down voted my question to -5 :D

Comment: Ouch! OK, I won't do it again! =) But on the other hand, I strongly recommend C, 'cause it has great graph capabilities. I see that you have posted an example... I'll see what I can do, until then, I think you're left with `identify`... =(

Comment: Thanks Al3xa :) .  Regarding identify - look at "library(digitize)"  Cheers,  Tal

Comment: Tal, you're a pal! =) I knew I'll bit my thong and whip myself because of "general purpose programming language" teasing... Thank you so much for this one, since it's very closely related to problem I'm about to tackle in a future research. =)

Comment: aL3xa, my pleasure to help :)  BTW, I believe this package has some way to go in terms of user interface.  I wanted to do it myself but didn't get around doing it.  If you happen to start improving the code, feel welcomed to email me about it (tal.galili@gmail.com) and I'll be happy to post it on my blog (www.r-statistics.com).  Cheers,  Tal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use package `raster` to extract xy coordinates from an image with specific values. Have a look at the package vignettes.

*EDIT*

Can you try this and tell me if it's in the ball park of what you're looking for?
I hope the code with comments is quite self-explanatory. Looking forward to your answer!

```
library(raster)
rst <- raster(nrows = 100, ncols = 100) #create a 100x100 raster
rst[] <- round(runif(ncell(rst))) #populate raster with values, for simplicity we round them to 0 and 1
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(rst) #see what you've got so far
rst.vals <- getValues(rst) #extract values from rst object
rst.cell.vals <- which(rst.vals == 1) #see which cells are 1
coords <- xyFromCell(rst, rst.cell.vals) #get coordinates of ones
rst[rst.cell.vals] <- NA #set those raster cells that are 1 to NA (you can play with rst[!rst.cell.vals] <- NA to exclude all others)
plot(rst) #a diag plot, should have only one color
```

Comment: Hi Romunov, thank you for the link.  I skimmed through the vignettes and couldn't find what you are talking about.  On what page is what you are referring? http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf

Comment: You basically manipulate your raster into setting all of the non-desired values to NA and extracting xy for the remaining values on the raster. That's how I do it for my project, but there could be a more elegant way I'm not familiar with yet. I admit, raster package takes some time before you get used to it and and feel its full power.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am struggling with the problem http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/image-classification-r/134107?noredirect=1#comment255465_134107. Would it be possible to provide any inputs? So far, I am using R raster package to get an image and then getValues function. I need guidelines regarding how to detect lines in an image....you seem to have a good handle on raster package and would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @user2543622 detecting lines in a raster image is no small thing. I'm thinking computer vision - train the program with enough images and use one of the libraries (or Python, it's well covered in this respect) to infer a given time.

Answer (score 4):

The [Medical Imaging](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MedicalImaging.html) Task View covers general image provessing, this may be a start.

Answer (score 4):

Following up after Dirk, yes check the medical imaging task view. Also look at Rforge,
Romain Francois has an RJImage package and another image processing package was recently registered. What you are looking for are segmentation algorithms. Your dots problem is much easier than the line problem. The first can be done with an RGB or greyscale filter, just doing some sort of radius search. Detecting linear features is harder. Once you hve the features extracted you can use a sweepline algorithm to detect intersections. EBIimage may have an example for detecting cells in the vignette.

Nicholas

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you very much for the detailed reply!

Due to the comments to the question, I added an example image to try to "solve".  If you might solve even the first example - it would be most useful.  Thanks again, Tal